# Covariance in the limit of random variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, limits-and-convergence

Suppose $\{X_n\}$ and $\{Y_n\}$ are two sequences of random variables and we know that $X_n \overset{L^2}{\to} X$ and $Y_n \overset{L^2}{\to} Y$, where $\overset{L^2}{\to}$ means converge in mean square sense. In addition, we know that $X$ and $Y$ are **independent** random variables, and both have finite mean and variance. I'm interested in showing
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} Cov(X_n, Y_n) = 0$$

I know that the above is not always true (e.g., see [this Math StackExchange thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291086/independence-of-random-variables-and-covariance-in-the-limit)). However, I wonder **what other conditions can one impose that will make it true?**

Comment: I'm a bit confused: doesn't this just follow from Holder's inequality? Note that the linked question assumes convergence in distribution, which is much weaker.

Comment: @LeoMoos, you are right that the L2 convergence here is much stronger than the convergence-in-distribution in the referenced link. That being said, would you mind elaborating a bit about how the limit of covariance can be proved (e.g., via Holder's inequality as you suggested)? Thanks!

Comment: By Holder's inequality $\mathbf{E}[X_n Y_n] - \mathbf{E}[XY] = \mathbf{E}[X_n ( Y_n - Y)] + \mathbf{E}[(X_n - X) Y] \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: @LeoMoos This makes sense. Does it matter that $X$ and $Y$ may not have zero mean? I.e., it is possible that $Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) - E(X)E(Y) \neq E(XY)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off $\mathbf{E}[X_n] \to \mathbf{E}[X]$ and $\mathbf{E}[Y_n] \to \mathbf{E}[Y]$ as $n \to \infty$, whence also $\mathbf{E}[X_n] \mathbf{E}[Y_n] \to \mathbf{E}[X] \mathbf{E}[Y]$. Via Holder's inequality one additionally has $\mathbf{E}[X_n Y_n] - \mathbf{E}[XY] = \mathbf{E}[X_n (Y_n - Y)] + \mathbf{E}[Y(X_n - X)] \to 0$.

Comment: Much appreciated!